# Can't display image in flask/jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am working on an assignment for a web application with flask, python and jinja2. Now I am trying to display an image on the page but it won't display.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='image/' + hottopic.image_name) }}" alt="{{ hottopic.image_name }}">
```

I can see the file name `alt="hottopic.image_name"` on web page.

```
route.py
    @bp.route('/hot-topic', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def hottopic():
        page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
        hottopics = HotTopic.query.order_by(HotTopic.id.desc()).paginate(
            page, current_app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], False)
        image_names = os.listdir('static/image')
        return render_template('hot_topic.html', title=_('Hot topic'), hottopics=hottopics.items, image_names=image_names)
```

I tried to move the file to static

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test.jpg') }}" alt="test.jpg">
```

I even move it to the templates file with a simple html but it still doesn't work.

```
<img src="test.jpg" alt="">
```

I checked the checkbox of "show image" in Internet Options, it was ticked.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial code shows the image in in a folder called images but you last one doesn’t reference that folder. So if it’s in a folder called images then this should work:

```
 <img src="{{url_for('static', ‘images/image_name.jpg')}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I finally found that I place the static file out of the working directory.